# BigQuery Scheduled Query Result: Execution Record Read/Written Not Consistent

Tags: google-bigquery

## BACKGROUND

I'm new to BigQuery and data management in general, and I've encountered an issue with scheduled query execution that I hope someone can help me with.

So my overall data workflow is as follow:

1. Different users add new row to Google Sheet A to Sheet 1/2/3/4/...
2. I create Google Sheet B to combine all sheets in Google Sheet A (using function such as `importrange` and `query` that sometimes takes couple secs to load, current total 1000+ rows)
3. I connect Google Sheet B to Big Query
4. Using the Table in Step 3, I create daily scheduled query to create a new table (overwrite, current total 27000+ rows)
5. I visualize table from Step 4 in Looker

The primary reason I chose to connect Google Sheets to BigQuery rather than querying directly in Google Sheets is because Looker seems to have limitations when working with Google Sheets datasets that exceed 27,000 rows.

## PROBLEM

It appears that some scheduled runs result in empty tables, despite the logs indicating a successful execution. I've noticed that the only way to fix this is by manually running a `scheduled backfill`

Here is the execution details from couple runs:

[Scheduled Day 1 (output table POPULATED)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoavT.png)

[Scheduled Day 2 (output table EMPTY)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jefy7.png)

[Scheduled Day 3 (output table EMPTY)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUvqo.png)

[Schedule Backfill (output table POPULATED)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14uzT.png)

[Empty Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL5hn.png)

What I notice is that the runs resulting in an empty table always show "Records Written: 0."

The Query:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  TOTAL_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'TOTAL (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  ORGANIC_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'ORGANIC (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  RESIDUE_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'RESIDUE (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  RECYCLABLE_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'RECYCLABLE (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  ALL_PLASTIC_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'ALL PLASTIC (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  PLASTIC_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'PLASTIC (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  PET_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'PET (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  HDPE_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'HDPE (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  PP_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'PP (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  PVC_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'PVC (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  KRESEK_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'KRESEK (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  LDPE_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'LDPE (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  MULTILAYER_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'MULTILAYER (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  ALL_NONPLASTIC_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'ALL NONPLASTIC (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  LOGAM_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'LOGAM (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  KERTAS_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'KERTAS (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  KACA_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'KACA (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE,
  HARI,
  Operasional,
  Jumlah_Hari_per_Bulan,
  Skor_Bulan,
  KARET_kg AS JumlahMasuk,
  'KARET (kg)' AS Kategori
FROM
  `dataset`
WHERE
  DATE IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  DATE,
  Kategori;
```

=========================================================

Any advice on steps to improve consistency is very appreciated!

Thank you